# Boris Johnson's derogatory comments about British business?

Tags: united-kingdom, boris-johnson

An [ING analysis](https://think.ing.com/downloads/pdf/article/five-thoughts-on-brexit-after-chequers) on the latest Brexit developments says:

> Another key Brexiteer, the Foreign Secretary Boris Johnson also quit this Monday in another big setback for the Prime Minister's authority. But keep in mind that there is a sense that his support among governing Conservative MPs has been waning, particularly after derogatory comments about British business were made public.

I know of several cases of Johnson making derogatory comments, but I'm not certain which comments the article refers to.

Does anyone know specifically which comments the above quote refers to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He [reportedly](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-44618154) used a simple expletive while reacting to business concerns about Brexit, namely:

> Fuck business

Comment: I do not approve the repeated edits. It's quite simple, he used that word, I provide a link to one of the most well respected news organisations in the world and they, quite appropriately, chose to reproduce that word. I happen to use the English language but I consider this to be an international website and I find the peculiar habit to replace some letters by asterisks or other symbols silly and unnecessary.

Comment: The BBC story has an offensive language warning, however, and the word in question first appears several lines below the warning.  Perhaps you could use a [spoiler block](https://politics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) to appease those who are concerned about the faint of heart.

Comment: @phoog I still find that somewhat silly (and the fact that many unrelated people feel the need to edit the word out quite fascinating) but it's a good solution, thanks!